Ctrl + Click on a React Component opens a window instead of opening the component file
Earlier, when I did Ctrl+leftClick on a React Component, it opened the file in which the component was created.
Now it opens a window containing the occurrence instead of opening the file.
Kindly help. Thanks.
import { StyleSheet, View } from "react-native";
import { Text } from "@/components/Themed";
import ButtonLink from "@/components/ButtonLink";
import ButtonContainer from "@/components/ButtonContainer";
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";

export default function Index() {
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <StatusBar style="auto" />
      <ButtonContainer>
        <ButtonLink
          href="/EpigeneticAwareness"
          imageSource={require("../../assets/epigenetic awareness.png")}
        />
        <ButtonLink
          href="/VRTherapy"
          imageSource={require("../../assets/vr therapy.png")}
        />
        <ButtonLink
          href="/AlcoholRecovery"
          imageSource={require("../../assets/alcohol recovery.png")}
        />
        <ButtonLink
          href="/SmokingCessation"
          imageSource={require("../../assets/smoking cessation.png")}
        />
        <ButtonLink
          href="/MentalHealthSupport"
          imageSource={require("../../assets/mental health support.png")}
        />
        <ButtonLink
          href="/ProgressTracking"
          imageSource={require("../../assets/progress tracking.png")}
        />
      </ButtonContainer>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
  title: {
    fontSize: 20,
    fontWeight: "bold",
  },
});


I tried to google but didn't find anything helpful.
